# Angular Error: ApplicationRef.tick is called recursively

Tags: javascript, angular

I am successfully emitting Event explicitly by running another change detection process outside Zone JS.
Though the change detection is running, **Error: ApplicationRef.tick is called recursively** error.
Looking at its API https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.3/packages/core/src/application_ref.ts#L347-L417
tick() method is getting stuck in Try-Catch block and not going to Finally hence throwing the recursive error.  Line 563-576

This is the method in which I am calling in the Application.tick()

```
public listenTeamOverview(assetName: string) {
    console.log('parent : ' + assetName);
    console.log('assetClass= ' + this.assetClass);
    this.assetClass = assetName;
    this.application.tick();
//  setTimeout(function(app) {
//      app.tick();
//  }, 2000, this.application);
}
```

Would just like to understand conceptually as to how to come out of this recursion process of tick() method?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You're running `tick` during the `Application.tick` execution. Why do you need it? You can just use setTimeout for that. After setTimeout tick will be called automatically

Comment: I tried to do the setTimeout, not working. adding the commented out timeout code in the question. there is something which I am doing wrong, can you help me out ?

Comment: You do not need to call app.tick inside setTimeout

Comment: Can you tell me the correct way please?

Comment: Just call `setTimeout` if your want to call the whole change detection cycle or `cdRef.detectChanges` if you want to run change detection for current component and its children

Comment: What is the reason of doing this? Can you reproduce your problem in plunker?

Comment: I am weak at creating Plunker but let say, there are 3 child components P, Q, R  of parent component A. Requirement is that on click of P, Q (side menu) should expand and R (bubble charts) should get rendered. To do this, I am using ApplicationRef.tick

Comment: If you don't use OnPush angular should update your bubble charts automatically

Comment: Just tell me How can I use setTimeout on ApplicationRef.tick() in A (Parent Component) to remove recursion? I tried using OnPush and by creating a service using Subject from Rxjs. Somehow, not getting success.

Answer (score 7):

Another working solution for me: use ChangeDetectorRef instead of ApplicationRef

```
constructor(private ref:ChangeDetectorRef) { }

somethingChanged() {
    this.ref.detectChanges();
}
```